# Javascript on Rails

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Just started to experiment with HTML5 features and really like the localStorage.

And now I wonder if it makes sense to create some libraries which make life easier. Something which easily persists objects from the localStorage to the server-DB. Something like a object.findAllByAttribute(Attribute) etc.

So my question is: is there already something out there which helps me to write offline html5 applications? If not, would it make sense or am I thinking the wrong way?

Comment: Hm. Not easy to select the right answer. I guess the backbone.js answer deserves the bounty (if no better answer is given in the next 15 hours), and it does fit to my question. But it now seems to me that I wasn't able to formulate my thoughts in the right way - so for me, (my own) javascriptMVC answer is the best.

Comment: Just found this great project: http://todomvc.com/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**backbone.js** is a Javascript framework which will help make that task easier. It has support for localStorage as well as sync from server.

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/

This is an example application which make use of localStorage.

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/todos.html

This uses backbone localStorage adapter.

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone-localstorage.html

Comment: good answer. nice framework. but it looks a bit too complicated. Will wait and see if we get simpler answers.

Comment: sorry for only getting +25. I'm sure I accepted your answer this morning, but I used my mobile webbrowser. It seems the ajax request didn't get through :-(

Comment: I did saw the answer accepted in the morning. I don't know why it is showing +25 only. May be some other problem.

Comment: btw: I tried to cantact stackoverflow team by email, but didn't get a response yet :-(

Comment: Update: I got feedback from the stackoverflow team. Bounties have been changes - Accepting the answer will not assign the bounty. I would have had to click the bounty icon in order to assign it, and I didn't :-( sorry.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't used it myself but https://github.com/wycats/jquery-offline might be quite a good fit.

Also there is js-model which supports localStorage https://github.com/benpickles/js-model, I have used it and it is very good, I think syncing between localStorage and your server is probably fairly app specific though.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another javascript library for handling localStorage: https://github.com/polvero/Kizzy

I have not used it, but it looks worthy of consideration.

Answer (score 2):

just found http://www.javascriptmvc.com/ . Looks interesting, simpler than backbone.js and closer to Rails or Grails.

But have to admit that the focus is not the offline feature. But I guess when you already have a model, offline isn't the big problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

things advanced and it seems that http://angularjs.org/ is what I was looking for at the time I asked the question.

There is also a great talk about using AngularJs together with Grails for creating SPI Applications: http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/home/developing-spi-applications-using-grails-and-angularjs